# Parse complex xml to fetch particular node text in c#

Tags: c#, xml, ssis-2017

Parsing XML file using SSIS / C#

operations like fetching record count from trailer , TIN  from body and store into a variable or somewhere temporarily(your suggestions please) for further processing. I don't want to store it in a table.

Please find the sample xml mentioned below

```
<ACOParticipantData xmlns:xsi="">
  <Header>
    <HeaderCode>HDR_PFPRVDR</HeaderCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <ACOProgCode>21</ACOProgCode>
  </Header>
  <Participants>
    <Participant>
      <ACO_ID>V199</ACO_ID>
      <TIN>123456789</TIN>
      <Old_TIN>987654321</Old_TIN>
      <Org_NPI>1234567890</Org_NPI>
      <Ind_NPI>1234567890</Ind_NPI>
      <CCN>123456</CCN>
      <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
      <PRG_Term_Dt>20161231</PRG_Term_Dt>
    </Participant>
  </Participants>
  <Trailer>
    <TrailerCode>TRL_PFPRVDR</TrailerCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</ACOParticipantData>
```

Comment: does your xml have blank namespace like `xmlns:xsi=""` or may be it contains some value?

Comment: There is no name space tag, anyway Does it really matters?

Comment: yes xml parsing is depends upon namespace so can i assume that there is no any namespace?

Comment: @er-shoaib yes please

Comment: so you need to fetch all TIN for all `Participants` in list right?

Comment: yeah. you are correct.

Comment: answer added view it might be it help you :)

Comment: if answer was helpful to your then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get fist get list of `Participants` then fetch all Participants tin number into list like

Here i created console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");

        List<long> tinList = new List<long>();

        tinList = doc.Descendants("Participants").Elements().Elements("TIN").Select(x => (long)x).ToList();

        foreach (long tin in tinList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tin);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:** (For 2 Participants)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class for each node and use XML deserialisation to create the object.

I had to remove the empty namespace as the deserialisation process requires a valid namespace.

Also you can change the type of the properties according to your needs.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class ACOParticipantData 
    {
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public Participant[] Participants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Header 
    {
        public string HeaderCode { get; set; }
        public string FileCreationDate { get; set; }
        public string ACOProgCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Participant 
    {
        public string ACO_ID { get; set; }
        public string TIN { get; set; }
        public string Old_TIN { get; set; }
        public string Org_NPI { get; set; }
        public string Ind_NPI { get; set; }
        public string CCN { get; set; }
        public string PRG_Eff_Dt { get; set; }
        public string PRG_Term_Dt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trailer 
    {
        public string TrailerCode { get; set; }
        public string FileCreationDate { get; set; }
        public string RecordCount { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var xmlString = @"<ACOParticipantData>
          <Header>
            <HeaderCode>HDR_PFPRVDR</HeaderCode>
            <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
            <ACOProgCode>21</ACOProgCode>
          </Header>
          <Participants>
            <Participant>
              <ACO_ID>V199</ACO_ID>
              <TIN>123456789</TIN>
              <Old_TIN>987654321</Old_TIN>
              <Org_NPI>1234567890</Org_NPI>
              <Ind_NPI>1234567890</Ind_NPI>
              <CCN>123456</CCN>
              <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
              <PRG_Term_Dt>20161231</PRG_Term_Dt>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
              <ACO_ID>V199</ACO_ID>
              <TIN>123456780</TIN>
              <Old_TIN>987654321</Old_TIN>
              <Org_NPI>1234567890</Org_NPI>
              <Ind_NPI>1234567890</Ind_NPI>
              <CCN>123456</CCN>
              <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
              <PRG_Term_Dt>20161231</PRG_Term_Dt>
            </Participant>
          </Participants>
          <Trailer>
            <TrailerCode>TRL_PFPRVDR</TrailerCode>
            <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
            <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
          </Trailer>
        </ACOParticipantData>";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ACOParticipantData));

        ACOParticipantData obj = null;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            obj = (ACOParticipantData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        if (obj == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var tin in obj.Participants.Select(x => x.TIN)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tin);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789
123456780
```